# Constrainting types in generics

Tags: haskell, generics

I'm trying to implement conversion to YAML for Generic types.

The simple conversion I implemented works well, but I would like to use their `Show` instance for the types like `data Foo = Bar | Biz`.

I was thinking of something like bellow. It correctly catches the types mentioned above, but fails on invoking the `show` as I'm not able to properly constraint it.

```hs
instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} (GToYaml x, GToYaml y) => GToYaml (D1 d (x :+: y)) where
  gToYaml x = string $ pack $ show $ to x
```

**Is it possible to somehow constraint for original type to have Generic and Show instances?** Or it should be handled somehow differently?

Comment: It *may* be possible to hack this together, but I'm fairly sure that the road you're going down is full of pain and tears. Once you start overlapping typeclass instances, you stop being able to reason about code really fast. My recommendation: Just tell users of `Foo`-like classes to implement `GToYaml` themselves and provide `defaultGToYaml` as a standalone function they can use to do so.

Comment: Yeah: it's always tempting to throw overlapping instances at situations like this, but it usually causes more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably, the original typeclass is something like

```
class ToYaml x where
  toYaml :: x -> Yaml
```

Suppose we define this auxiliary datatype and typeclass:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.Proxy
import GHC.Generics

data HowToConvertToYaml = NormalCase | SpecialCase

class ToYaml' (how :: HowToConvertToYaml) x where
  toYaml' :: Proxy how -> x -> Yaml
```

`HowToConvertToYaml` is being used as a [`DataKind`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/data_kinds.html), to provide one piece of extra information to `ToYaml'`: whether we are in the special case or not. This allows us to define different instances for each case:

```
instance Show x => ToYaml' SpecialCase x where
   toYaml' _ = undefined

instance (Generic x, GToYaml (Rep x)) => ToYaml' NormalCase x where
   toYaml' _ = undefined
```

The problem is that we want to use `ToYaml`, not `ToYaml'`. We need a way to automatically compute the `HowToConvertToYaml` for each type, and then make the  `ToYaml` instance delegate on the `ToYaml'` one.

We can use a type family:

```
type family FindHowToConvertToYaml rep :: HowToConvertToYaml where
  FindHowToConvertToYaml (D1 _ (_ :+: _)) = SpecialCase
  FindHowToConvertToYaml _ = NormalCase
```

And `ToYaml` in terms of `ToYaml'` would be:

```
instance (Generic x, ToYaml' (FindHowToConvertToYaml (Rep x)) x) => ToYaml x where
  toYaml = toYaml' (Proxy @(FindHowToConvertToYaml (Rep x)))
```

Comment: It's the right approach except instead of parameterizing a type class I would define a parameterized newtype

Comment: @Iceland_jack Would that involve `DerivingVia`? Something like `deriving (ToYaml x) via (NewtypeHelper (FindHowToConvertToYaml (Rep x)) x)` ?